# Use Excel data as dropdown choice in PowerApps

Tags: microsoft, microsoft-power-automate-desktop

I have a Power Apps canvas app set up with the dropdowns (Name, Age, Gender). The user can select the values and hit a button that will write the information via Power Automate to a location on the computer as a text file. I would like input to see if it is possible to use an excel sheet with the same columns (Name, Age, Gender) and different values in the rows and write the information for all automatically.
Essentially, my logic is something like this:
Read a total of 10 rows at a time from excel and feed it to a table in MS PowerApps. Display this table or gallery in PowerApps. In Powerapps do something like:

```
i = 0
for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
read row(i)
select dropdowns
push button to write kfile
i++
//If there are less than 10 rows, read upto the row which contains data and then exit the loop.
```

I understand that this not close to the accurate solution at all, and need some (maybe a lot) of guidance to get this accomplished. Any help is appreciated!